# Copy Range to new workbook - Not copying, error 9

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving a Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range.

The error occurs at the end.. I am trying to open a new spreadsheet, copy edited information into it, and then I will use a script following this to dump 8-12 more files based on selection INTO 'FName' ... which may or may not work.

This is highlighted when I click debug:

```
Workbooks("TFR7").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:V" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(FName).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

I do not understand the error here? Is it my range selection to copy over?

Side note: I AM working to learn how to remove the instances of select, etc. FYI

Code is below:

```
Sub OpenReportThenEdit()

'This will open a designated report and edit it
'File pathway and name must be correct
'Any adjustments to file layout could 'break' macro
'First file will always be TFR7 and from there can go into more


'Currently only works for TFR7

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FName As String

'Open a report, delete header/footer rows

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\USER\Downloads\TFR7", False, False)
wb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:5").EntireRow.Delete
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
wb.Sheets(1).Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete

'Edit Sheet Font/Size

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 9
End With

'Edit Sheet Alignment, etc.

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
End With

'Replace 'text to columns' and convert dates to Excel Date Value before
'Paste Values' to remove formula

Columns("L:O").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(LEFT(RC[4],10))"
Range("L2").Copy Destination:=Range("L2:O2")
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("L2:O" & LastRow).FillDown
Range("P1:S1").Copy Destination:=Range("L1:O1")

Columns("L:O").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

'Delete old date columns, remove duplicate values (by tracking numbers)

Columns("P:S").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:V" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=19, Header:= _
    xlYes

'Select cells with values, turn them blue (because silly people want them blue)

LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:V" & LastRow).Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

'Open Workbook, set Workbook as Destination for

FName = "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Daily_" & _
        Format(Date, "mmdd") & ".xlsm"

Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

Workbooks("TFR7").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:V" & LastRow).Copy Destination:= _
        Workbooks(FName).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wait, do I need to 'Set FName' as some form of variable? 7 days into this, teaching myself, if anyone can point me in the right direction I will be exceptionally grateful.

Comment: The **reason** for the error is that `Workbooks("C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Daily_0506.xlsm")` won't work, it needs to just be `Workbooks("Daily_0506.xlsm")` (i.e. without the path).  The answer from Macro Man should solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work with objects instead:

```
Dim otherWB As Excel.Workbook

'// other code here

Set otherWB = Workbooks.Add
otherWB.SaveAs Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

'// wb is already set to original workbook, otherWB is set to new workook
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:V" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=otherWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```